# How do you add page numbers to Page & Browser Titles in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, pagination

Joomla seems to have no default pagination support built in... Which I'm sure isn't right. It's meant to be very extensive for SEO customisation.

But my question here is, the pagination at the bottom of the page is giving URLs such as `/itemlist?start=4` - Where 4 is the item number to start the list from.

The problem here is that, all of the pages have the same browser title. How can I append 'Page #' on the end of a browser title, without using a plugin?

UPDATE:

I've stumbled upon this API page https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JPagination.html and this seems to reference the following, which I'll try and use, and see if I can get a result into the title tag somehow.

> **getPagesCounter**
>
> Create and return the pagination pages counter string, ie. Page 2 of
>   4.
>
> `getPagesCounter() : string`

UPDATE:

I've no idea how to output this string onto a page, I've tried using `echo getPagesCounter()`, but that returns null. Any help or info is greatly appreciated. How can I use this function in template overrides?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$this->pagination->pagesCurrent` to get the current page #.

You can then use

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->setTitle( $document->getTitle() . ' - Page ' . $this->pagination->pagesCurrent);
```

in `components > com_content > views > category > tmpl > blog.php` to add the page number to the title.

You should of course copy `blog.php` to your template folder to create an override instead of editing the core Joomla files.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this in a content plugin, by checking the GET variable, and then using something like the below:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$this->setTitle( $this->getTitle() . ' - ' . 'Page N');
```

Where N is the number of the current page that you can get from $_GET.

Comment: I want to get rid of URL parameters, so won't that mean I won't be able to get anything from $_GET? Besides, I don't have page numbers displaying in the URL, when I view page 5, the URL shows as /itemlist?start=16